# Azure Bicep template deployment failure with error: "The value of parameter linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path is invalid.\"

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep

I created a bicep templated to deploy on Azure (using bash) a linux vm with the associated resources (nic, vnet, subnet, publicIP). Part of the deployment fails; where all the associated resources are deployed but the vm itself fails to deploy.

The error is as follows:
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment            operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "InvalidParameter",\r\n    "message": "Destination path for SSH public keys is currently limited to its default value /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys  due to a known issue in Linux provisioning agent.",\r\n    "target": "linuxConfiguration.ssh.publicKeys.path"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}

The bicep template provided by microsoft uses the path: '/home/${adminUsername}/.ssh/authorized_keys'

I can't seem to figure out a way for it to deploy. Any assistance would greatly appreciated.

**Here is the bicep file that causes the error:**

```
@description('Name of the VM')
param vmName string = 'stagingLinuxVM'

@description('location for all resources')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

@description('vm sizes allowed RAM & temp storage in GiB per tier (respectively): 0.5/4; 1/4; 2/4; 4/8; 8/16')
@allowed([
  'Standard_B1s'
  'Standard_B1ms'
  'Standard_B2s'
  'Standard_B2ms'
])
param vmSize string = 'Standard_B1s'

@description('Username for the VM')
param adminUsername string

@description('SSH Key for the Virtual Machine')
@secure()
param adminPasswordKey string

@description('name of VNET')
param virtualNetworkName string = 'vnet'

@description('name of the subnet in the virtual network')
param subnetName string = 'Subnet'

param dnsLabelPrefix string = toLower('${vmName}-${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}')

var osDiskType = 'Standard_LRS'
var networkInterfaceName = '${vmName}nic'
var addressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/16'
var publicIPAddressName = '${vmName}PublicIP'
var subnetAddressPrefix = '10.1.0.0/24'
var linuxConfiguration = {
  disablePasswordAuthentication: true
  provisionVMAgent: true
  ssh: {
    publicKeys: [
      {
        path: '/home/${adminUsername}/.ssh/authorized_keys'
        keyData: adminPasswordKey
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource nic 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2021-08-01' = {
  name: networkInterfaceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          subnet: {
            id: subnet.id
          }
          privateIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
          publicIPAddress: {
            id: publicIP.id
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-08-01' = {
  name: virtualNetworkName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        addressPrefix
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource subnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2021-08-01' = {
  parent: vnet
  name: subnetName
  properties: {
    addressPrefix: subnetAddressPrefix
    privateEndpointNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
    privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies: 'Enabled'
  }
}

resource publicIP 'Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses@2021-08-01' = {
  name: publicIPAddressName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
  }
  properties: {
    publicIPAllocationMethod: 'Dynamic'
    publicIPAddressVersion: 'IPv4'
    dnsSettings: {
      domainNameLabel: dnsLabelPrefix
    }
    idleTimeoutInMinutes: 4
  }
}

resource vm 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2021-11-01' = {
  name: vmName
  location: location
  properties: {
    hardwareProfile: {
      vmSize: vmSize
    }
    osProfile: {
      adminPassword: adminPasswordKey
      adminUsername: adminUsername
      computerName: vmName
      linuxConfiguration: linuxConfiguration
    }
    storageProfile: {
      imageReference: {
        offer: 'UbuntuServer'
        publisher: 'Canonical'
        sku: '18.04-LTS'
        version: 'latest'
      }
      osDisk: {
        createOption: 'FromImage'
        deleteOption: 'Delete'
        diskSizeGB: 32
        osType: 'Linux'
        managedDisk: {
          storageAccountType: osDiskType
        }
      }
    }
    networkProfile: {
      networkInterfaces: [
        {
          id: nic.id
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

output adminUsername string = adminUsername
output hostname string = publicIP.properties.dnsSettings.fqdn
output sshComand string = 'ssh ${adminUsername}@${publicIP.properties.dnsSettings.fqdn}'
```

Comment: Please include the Bicep files so we can see what you're working with. We can then debug the templates to see what may be missing.

Comment: @Stringfellow thank you, I have added the bicep code above.